# Scala parser combinators and Reader infinite loop

Tags: parsing, scala, parser-combinators

I am a little confused by the Scala parser combinators.
I'm using a custom implementation of Reader to directly read a list of tokens:

```
private class Token_Reader(tokens: List[Token], val pos: Token_Pos) extends Reader
{
  def first = if(atEnd) null else tokens.head
  def rest = if(atEnd) this else new Token_Reader(tokens.tail, new Token_Pos(pos.p + 1))
  def atEnd = tokens.isEmpty
}
```

What puzzles me is that `atEnd` seems to be completely ignored by the actual parsers, resulting in an infinite loop / infinite recursion when using `*`/`rep`.

Comment: See also http://www.scala-lang.org/node/5658 which poses the same question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that it will fix this issue, but in the Reader implementations I see in the Scala source, the `first` method returns an end of file character rather than null when at the end.  And I believe it's generally good to avoid nulls...

For example, in `CharSequenceReader` it looks like

```
  /** Returns the first element of the reader, or EofCh if reader is at its end 
   */
  def first = 
    if (offset < source.length) source.charAt(offset) else EofCh
```

And this character is defined in the companion object:

```
object CharSequenceReader {
  final val EofCh = '\032'
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. I could, of course, create an extra subclass of `Token` and return that instead of `null`, but I doubt that that solves the issue.

It might just be a design decision in how Scala's parser combinators work, but that would pose the question what the `atEnd` method is for.